# nginx: как при помощи proxy_pass прокинуть и 80, и 443-й порты?

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, gitlab

До сих пор я использовал nginx достаточно тривиальным образом: на него "приземлялись" http/https обращения, и он служил "базой", на которой работал certbot и обновлял letsencrypt - сертификаты для разных доменов.
Как правило, статические сайты хостились на самом сервере с nginx, а для тех, которые обеспечивали api - работа *после* nginx шла по http, то есть, nginx работал в роли ssl-termination. То есть, "из интернета мы обращаемся по https, а внутри сети у нас ходит http" - и все были счастливы.

Но наступил момент, когда мне "захотелось странного". А именно - внутри сети появился gitlab.

Гитлаб - это штука весьма самостоятельная, и он *сам* хостит https-сертификаты. То есть, если у меня теперь происходит обращение снаружи по имени гитлаба - то мне надо https - запрос так и отфорвардить внутрь сети.

При этом я могу по всякому настраивать http/https порты на самом гитлабе, но сейчас ониу меня настроены на 8080 и 8443.

я почитал разные советы, про директиву proxy_ssl_server_name, но ни один их них мне, вроде бы, не подходит. И старый способ с ssl-termination на уровне nginx мне тоже не подходит.

Типичный файл для proxy_pass выглядит примерно так:

```
    server {

        root /var/www/<folder_of_site>;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mygitlab.myserver.ru www.mygitlab.myserver.ru;
        client_max_body_size 2048m;

        location / {
              proxy_redirect          http://192.168.0.10:8080 /; 
              proxy_pass_header       Server;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
              proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
              proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
              proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
              proxy_connect_timeout   5;
              proxy_read_timeout      240;
              proxy_intercept_errors  on;

              proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.10:8080;
        }
    }
```

Обратите внимание: здесь нигде не написано, что перекидываются соединения с 80-го порта, видимо, это поведение по умолчанию. Вот если бы я в директиве `location` мог указать порт - я бы просто два раза повторил тот кусочек файла, который сожержит внутри себя директивы `proхy_...` - и получил бы желаемый результат, видимо.

А желаемое поведение nginx-а я проиллюстрирую вот такой картинкой:

[image: nginx and gitlab]

Буду очень благодарен за советы!

**Что в итоге**

Уважаемые господа, этот пункт добавлен уже после того, как всё получилось. Я последовал совету **Pak Uula** и сделал так,К ак он в своём ответе называет "правильно": теперь у меня nginx занмается ssl-termination, а Gitlab "просто работает". Оказывается, не нужно предпринимать дополнительных усилий для отключения https у гитлаба, в [руководстве](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html) пишут "By default, Omnibus GitLab does not use HTTPS".

Таким образом, у меня всё заработало. Для тех, кто будет читать это пост я напишу даже чуть чуть подробнее:

*0-й шаг*: в DMZ на машинке с адресом `192.168.0.10` я поднимаю гитлаб в контейнере командой типа

```
sudo docker run --detach \
  --hostname docker.junecat.ru \
  --publish 8443:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 1022:22 \
  --name gitlab1 \
  --restart always \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
  --volume $GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
  --shm-size 256m \
  gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

*1-й шаг*: создаю для nginx файл `/etc/nginx/sites-available/docker.junecat.ru` с таким содержимым:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root /var/www/docker.junecat.ru/;

  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name docker.junecat.ru www.docker.junecat.ru;

  location / {
          proxy_redirect          http://192.168.0.10:8080/  /;
          proxy_pass_header       Server;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header        X-Scheme $scheme;
          proxy_set_header        X-NginX-Proxy true;
          proxy_connect_timeout   5;
          proxy_read_timeout      240;
          proxy_intercept_errors  on;

          proxy_pass              http://192.168.0.10:8080/;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}
```

обратите внимание, что команда

```
    sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/docker.junecat.ru /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

уже выполнена ранее, и сайт есть не только в "доступных", но и в "разрешенных".

Как видите, пока никакого `https` и сертификатов - нет. Они возникнут на

*2-й шаг*: говорим сертботу получить сертификаты и исправить в соответствии с ними файл nginx'а:

```
    sudo certbot --nginx -d docker.junecat.ru -d www.docker.junecat.ru
```

Ну, и в заключение - исправленная картинка, как всё сейчас работает (просто чтоы никого не вводить в заблуждение):

[image: как работает]

Comment: Можно попробовать с помощью `map $scheme` создать переменную с нужным портом и потом использовать эту переменную в proxy_pass https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Comment: @andreymal - хм, хорошая мысль, сейчас попробую "копать" в эту сторону! Спасибо за идею!

Comment: Вот тут даже какой-то пример конфига нагуглился https://www.valynkin.ru/tomcat-behind-ssl-nginx-reverse-proxy.html

Comment: @andreymal - а в этом примере в конфиге nginx'a переменная $port - это встроенная переменная самого nginx?

Comment: Мне кажется что проще отобрать у гитлаба самостоятельность и не городить огород. Я лично не представляю как нормально сделать на одном интерфейсе и одном порту одновременно и проксирование и терминирование ssl.

Comment: @S.H. её создаёт map

Comment: @AlexeyTen - я думал над этим, но у меня нет положительного примера, как у кого то это получилось. В документации написано довольно мутно, какое то это "очень нетипичное использование" гитлаба. У вас нет положительного опыта "чтобы отобрать, а оно всё ранво работало"? А потом обратите внимание: порты - разные, и мне нужно только проксирование! как раз ssl-терминирование для этого конкртетного хоста я хочу у nginx'а отобрать!

Comment: @andreymal " её создаёт map" - прошу прощения, проглядел! Спасибо! И еще один, важный ворос: в примере, на который Вы указали, ssl_certificate - это обязательная штука?То есть, бех них работать не будет? Просто для меня это означает, что один и тот же сертификат просто придётся класть на два сервера.

Comment: @S.H. обязательная, иначе nginx не сможет расшифровать и распарсить входящий http-запрос. Если nginx не делает ничего кроме перенаправления на гитлаб, то тогда наверное nginx вообще не нужен? Если же nginx делает что-то ещё, то ему надо расшифровывать запросы для обработки

Comment: @andreymal - мне кажется, там чтобы работать с именем хоста - не надо расшифровывать трафик. Опять таки, кажется, что для этого используется такая штука: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication . А логика здесь такая: у меня один nginx обслуживает несколько доментов. У каждого домена - свой сертификат, а висит всё это на одном IP. Так что, вроде бы, если бы сертификат был нужен для понимания, запрос на какой домен пришел - то возникла бы проблема курицыи яйца: при приходе нового запроса - каким из сертификатов его пытаться расшифровать?

Comment: @S.H. теоретически запрос может прийти без SNI (от каких-нибудь супер-старых клиентов), тогда nginx будет использовать сертификат по умолчанию. Теоретически, наверное, можно определить, обрабатывать или тупо проксировать запрос, основываясь на SNI, но не слышал о том, чтобы nginx умел что-то подобное

Comment: @andreymal - спасибо, что Вы мне это пояснили. я реально не знал, как это устроено. То есть, практически nginx работает так: если в запросе есть sni - он использует информацию из sni. в противном случае - обрабатывает запрос при помощи дефолтного сертификата. Так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По умолчанию деректива `server` создаёт конфигурацию, которая слушает 80-й порт. Чтобы указать порт для сервера, используйте дерективу `listen`. Если в одном блоке `server` несколько `listen`, то созданный сервер будет слушать все указанные порты.

В вашем случае я бы сделал две записи `server`, одну HTTP для порта `80`, вторую STREAM для порта `443 ssl`.

Почему `stream` для 443-го порта. Если делать для этого порта простой блок `server`, то в него нужно добавлять сертификаты, которые, как вы написали, хранятся в gitlab. Поэтому нужно просто транслировать tcp трафик между внешним портом и портом 8443 gitlab-а. В минимальном варианте это может выглядеть вот так:

```
stream {
    # ...
    server {
        listen     0.0.0.0:443;
        proxy_pass 192.168.0.10:8443;
    }
}
```

При такой настройке весь трафик, идущий на 443-й порт, будет перенаправляться на бэкэнд с адресом 192.168.0.10, порт 8443. Вся обработка TLS/SSL перекладывается на бэкэнд.

Но на самом деле стал бы делать по-другому. Все запросы на 80-й порт я бы перенаправлял на 443-й, а бизнес-логику повесил уже на защищенный порт. То есть я бы забил на возможности gitlab по работе с HTTPS и оставил бы только HTTP.

1. Перенаправление всех запросов, вне зависимости от имени, на защищенный порт

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

2. Прокси на защищенном порту (минимальная конфигурация)

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name mygitlab.myserver.ru www.mygitlab.myserver.ru;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.10:8080;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<server name>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<server name>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Сертификаты для защищенного сервера я обычно получаю через `certbot`. Сертификаты храню на входном сервере, а внутри периметра трафик ходит в открытом виде.

FYI, в сервере, который работает на `proxy_pass` инструкция `index` избыточна, ведь все запросы вы перенаправляете в gitlab.

Comment: Очень крутой ответ! Большое спасибо, уже проверяю у себя!

Comment: В общем, еще рах спасибо за ответ! Я напрасно боялся: оказывается, про гитлаб пишут "By default, Omnibus GitLab does not use HTTPS". Поэтому получилось всё так, как Вы советовали: nginx осуществляет ssl-termination и создаёт прокси. Я добавлю в свой вопрос финальный пункт "как в результате сделал"

Comment: @S.H. Рад что ответ помог. Вы в ответе в примерах конфига и команды certbot указали DNS имя сервера. Может быть его стоит скрыть?

Comment: Спасибо за совет! ну, теоретически может найтись психологически неуравновешенный друг, который решит меня атаковать... Но, если такой найдётся - он может сопоставить множество моих ответов на этом сайте и всё равно "вычислить" меня. Лучше не иметь друзей! (таких). Так что спасибо, но для определенности - пока оставлю. Может, потом поменяю на что то вроде example.com