# Как пробросить порты из удаленного компа на локальный, чтобы с домашнего компа заходить в сетку удаленного компа?

Tags: сеть, windows-10, rdp

Удаленный рабочий стол Win 10, локальный (рабочий) комп Win 10. Как прокинуть порты таким образом, чтобы можно было открывать сайты вида office.local с домашнего компа?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Мне кажется, там прокидкой портов не обойдётся.

чтобы сайт вида `office.local` открылся на домашнем компе - надо, чтобы сначала сработало разрешение имен. То есть, Вам надо каким то образом заставить домашний комп ходить к рабочему DNS'у, который - один во всём мире - только и знает, что это за `office.local` такой.

Чтобы это работало - уже нужен VPN, так как - ну, как то традиция такая - офисные DNS'ы, которые, в большинстве своём, просто находятся на виндовых домен-контроллерах, не торчат в интернет.

Неплохим решением была бы организация доступа через OpenVPN. Но настроить такое Вам на работе могут только в том случае, если работа сама этого захочет - это "подпольно" не сделаешь.

Если хочется все сделать *самому, молча и незаметно* - приглядитесь к такому решению - [tailscale.com](https://tailscale.com/)

Это VPN, который практически не надо конфигурировать. Вот после его запуска - меняем DNS на домашнем компе на рабочий.
И пробуем. Если не работает - приходите в комментарии, будем думать дальше!

==============================

**После уточнений в комментариях** я могу дополнить свой ответ работающим рецептом.

Итак, проблема:

У автора вопроса есть полный контроль над домашним компом (что естественно) и над выделенной ему на работе рабочей станцией (что, по кррайней мере, приятно). Он хочет на домашнем компе "разглядывать" всякие ресурсы, которые находятся в рабочей сети, но "за пределами рабочей станции".

я полностью смоделировал ситуацию.

У меня есть:

"Домашний комп":

IP 192.168.0.101

*"Рабочий комп"*

IP 172.19.110.124, назовём его *workstation*
на нём установлен tailscale, и он получает
`IP 100.96.83.8`

Git-комп:

`IP 172.19.110.125`, и на нём tailscale не установлен.
Откликается на имя `gitlab.mycompany.ru`

Задача: с домашнего компа открывать (для начала - в браузере) `https://gitlab.mycompany.ru`

Итак,с домашнего компа я могу сделать `ping 100.96.83.8` и пинг пройдёт

Но `ping gitlab.mycompany.ru` не пройдёт, даже если я заменю имя на IP.

не проблема. Прописываю хост

```
    100.96.83.8 gitlab.mycompany.ru
```

в hosts на домашнем компе. Обратите внимание, это "неправильный" адрес для компа! имя - от Git - компа, а адрес - от workstation, причем от той "сетевой карты", которая соответсвует tailscale

Затем, запускаю на workstation любой прокси, который слущает порты 80 и 443 и перенаправляет пакеты на gitlab.mycompany.ru.

вот картинка с настройками прокси (я использовал PortTunnel, но это вопрос вкуса). Обратите внимание, там два аналогичных правила, на картинке показано только одно. Другое отличается только номерами портов.

[image: port tunel - 443]

**Запускаю прокси, на домашнем компе захожу на gitlab.mycompany.ru
Домашний комп "думает", что gitlab.mycompany.ru - это tailscale'овский адрес компа workstation,
и шлет пакеты туда. Там их ловит прокси, и перенаправляет на "настоящий" gitlab.mycompany.ru**

Выглядит примерно так: (там два окна, браузер (с неправильным сертификатом - потому что я на домашний комп самосгенерированный сертификат с работы не ставил - и окно, в котором виден IP.

Еще одно дополнение: внимательный читатель может заметить, что так мы получили доступ только к "одному ресурсу" в рабочей сети. Другие ресурсы можно "вывести наружу", например, использовав другие номера портов: например, 80 и 443 для гита, 8080 и 8443 - для почты

[image: браузер на домашнем компе]

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Да openvpn запретили использовать, хотя можно прокинуть, админские доступы есть.  Но tailscale, сейчас попробую

Comment: Блин, это просто спасение. Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Блин, единственное не работает подключение к офисному домену office.local, хотя днс прописал офисные, с RDP компа.

Comment: При подключении к домену возможны следующие "грабли": имя пользователя должно влючать имя домена. Например, net use X: \\office_server\folder /user:domainname\username или  net use X: \\office_server\folder /user:username@domainname Я писал, конечно, из головы, но вот эти ДВА метода называть имя пользователя - надо держатьв голове

Comment: Я честно говоря сейчас под убунтой сижу. Но тем не менее net use монтирует сетевой диск вроде как. А мне нужно открыть веб интерфейс git.office.local, или без сетевого диска оно и не откроется?

Comment: откроется.
Но к гиту надо "ходить" двумя путями: по https - это вроде должно работать сразу. Если не работает - попробуйте прописать IP адрес git.office.local в файл hosts. А "вторым номером" идет доступ по ssh. Ну, чтобы команды типа git clone git@git.office.local:troodi/todoer.git работали. Для  ssh нужен, понятное дело, 22-й порт на тачанке git.office.local. Для https - разрешение имен браузером и доступ к git.office.local по https. Ну, а теперьу Вас есть всё для диагностики :-)

Comment: Ну до 22 порта ещё далеко. Потому что я не могу всё равно достучаться до вебстраницы. То есть она пингуется, но через браузер отдает timeout хромовский и вот тут я ловлю тупняк почему так. То есть вроде как к сетке то подключился, а доступа к домену нет.

Comment: Чтобы ходить по https на git - там же, наверное, что то типа Gitlab установлено? - доступа к домену не нужно. Можно проверить при помощи curl или wget. Я предполагаю следующее: вот у Вас tailscale установлен на домашнем компе с Убунтой и на рабочем компе с Win10. Эти два компа друг друга видят. Но чтобы с компа на убунет увидеть git - надо, чтобы пакеты с рабочего компа (куда они доходят) передались еще на один комп -комп с гитом. А там - скорее всего, нужно или добавлять на комп с Win10 статический маршрут, либо - если есть такая возможность - плюхнуть клиента tailscale прямо на тачку с git

Comment: я придумал хак: поднять на компе с Win10 nginx, который "научить" при помощи proxy-pass передавать запрос дальше, на git. Хотя костыль, конечно...

Comment: Я вот тоже сейчас сделал через прокси пасс, но он не проксирует. Пока не могу понять в чем дело.

Comment: "Пока не могу понять в чем дело": А не может быть проблемы в том, что доступ идет по https? я тут поднимал такую тему, возможно, это как то поможет... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1397211/

Comment: Короче, проще другую работу поискать :) Фигней какой-то занимаюсь, почему программистам нельзя дать нормальный доступ к репам - загадка. Кодить в RDP это безумие, тем более на винде с тупящим докером.

Comment: да, это правда. Может, проще попросить "прямой VPN" к гиту? Это вроде как самая безболезненная операция

Comment: Не дают, третий день говорят, что это политика компании. Работал с форекс и криптовалютных проектах, всегда нормально прокидывали VPN, а тут проблема. Хотя я тут всего 3 дня, но если нет, то нет. Обидно, конечно.

Comment: Ну, могу немного позавидовать :-) Думаю, что работа всё таким интересная. Слушай, а что, если поступить крайне просто: вот у тебя есть выделенный тебе на работе Win10 - комп. Он полностью под твоим контролем, то есть, на нём ты можешь запускать всё, что хочешь. Что уже доказал, запустив там tailscale. А что, если туда плюхнуть простой tcp-прокси, который будет уже на этом компе мапить нужные тебе порты на порты компа с git-ом? Мне под руку для винды попался проксяк, который называется PortTunnel - но, в пинципе, такого софта - дофига. И тогда "его порты станут твоими портами"

Comment: Хм, давай попробую, спасибо. Отпишу как разберусь что к чему.
P.S. Ну прикол то в том что права админские, то есть вообще защита сомнительная, тем что нельзя локально работать. Закинуть на сетевой диск можно что с локалки, что с RDP фигню.

Comment: Такс, тут тогда вопрос, например пробрасываем порт 80, как тогда подключаться к определенному домену? Их же несколько `git.office.local` и `mail.office.local` и т.д.
Что-то я просто уже поплыл, перестал соображать как оно работать будет

Comment: я вот одного не понимаю: в вопросе-ответе проявлена изобретательность выше среднего, объяснены шаги, при помощи которых мы достигли результата... и все таки ответ заминусован. Не то, чтобы меня это злило, но вечный вопрос - а почему?